# Thymeleaf : How to use Custom Message Key in JSR-303 Annotation

Tags: java, message, thymeleaf

Use Thymeleaf

Person.java

```
public class Person {
    @NotEmpty(message="{Valid.Password}")
    private String password;
}
```

message.properties

```
Valid.Password = Password is Empty!!
```

Login.html

```
<span class="error" th:errors="person.password"></span>
```

`th:errors` can not retrieve 'Valid.Password' Message
That area is shown as empty.

if message key change to NotEmpty.person.password of message.properties, then it is working.

how to use custom message key?

Comment: Try to check in your JSR 303 implementation library what its the message key for @NotEmpty restriction, you can override this in messages.properties

Comment: @fjtorres when you say message key, I guess you mean the value that appears in the javadocs. By the way, did you study at the University of Almeria (Spain)? Just curious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using javax.validation constrains on class and adding custom messages requires you to basically override default messages.
for example:

```
public class Vehicle implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Size(min=17, max=17, message="VIN number must have 17 characters")
    private String vin;


    @NotEmpty
    @Pattern(regexp="[a-z]*", flags = Pattern.Flag.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
    private String make;

    @NotEmpty
    @Pattern(regexp="[a-z]*", flags = Pattern.Flag.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
    private String model;
```

To override default values, you insert custom message in the validation itself like for VIN, or add them to the messages.properties file:

```
# Validation messages
notEmpty.message = The value may not be empty!
notNull.message = The value cannot be null!
```

In this way you are overriding default values for:

```
javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty.message
javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message
```

If you require specific message for different fields, your message properties should include them in the following format: [constraintName.Class.field]. For example:

```
NotEmpty.Vehicle.model = Model cannot be empty!
```

If you do not include override values like one above, it will show default value, or general override like notEmpty message.

Of course, there are other ways of showing validation messages, like using information you need from the ConstraintViolation object that comes out of the Validator instance.

Hope this helps,

Comment: I followed your method without success. I created the messages.properties file with specified format: [constraintName.Class.field] and also for generic cases notEmpty.message = .... but it was ignored. The only way to override the validation messages I found is creating the file ValidationMessages.properites but it still doesn't allow to make it individually by classes. I wonder if you the sample you posted before in github or similar to check it.

Comment: Try putting attribute you pass to the view in stead of the class in format: [constraintName.Attribute.field] replacing [constraintName.Class.field].

Comment: To be more specific. `class Person{ 
    @Size(min=2, max=30)
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Min(value = 18L)
    private Integer age;}`

My form:

`<form action="#" th:action="@{/form}" th:object="${person}" method="post">

Name:<input type="text" th:field="*{name}"/>
            <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}">Name error</td>
        
Age:<input type="text" th:field="*{age}"/>
            <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('age')}" th:errors="*{age}">Name error</td>
        
                <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
    </table>

</form>`

Comment: Based on my previous comment, what is the partAttribute? 
I understand the field is the th:field value in the form (name, age).What I don't get is the partAttribute. By the way, I uploaded the sample code to gitHub: https://MichaelKnight@github.com/MichaelKnight/ValidandoFormularios.git

Comment: OK, finally I got it. Instead of the ClassName I had to use the object name and it works like a charm. NotNull.person.age=THE AGE CANNOT BE NULL!!!! I uploaded the code to github for further references for any fellow member.