# Spring boot + Thymeleaf custom error messages

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using spring boot and thymeleaf for a web application.

I want to customize the validation error messages instead of using the default ones. I found the way to do it is creating a file called messages.properties with the constraints and the message. I also found I can create custom messages based on the class I am targeting and I can also use internationalization methods based on this.

In order to override the default messages I created my own messages.properties file:

```
Size.message=El tamño no es correcto
NotNull.message=No puede ser nulo
Min.message=No cumple con el minimo
```

I set the constraints in my class:

```
public class Person {

    @Size(min=2, max=30)
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Min(value = 18L)
    private Integer age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

This is my form:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/form}" th:object="${person}" method="post">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{name}"/></td>
            <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}">Name error</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Age:</td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{age}"/></td>
            <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('age')}" th:errors="*{age}">Name error</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</form>
```

And I placed the messages.properties in the resources folder:

[image]

According to these links I am doing correctly:

[Thymeleaf : How to use Custom Message Key in JSR-303 Annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323655/thymeleaf-how-to-use-custom-message-key-in-jsr-303-annotation)

[How to include message.properties with thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30106659/how-to-include-message-properties-with-thymeleaf)

But it still not display the custom error messages I wrote.

Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance for your help.

GitHub with the sample code: https://MichaelKnight@github.com/MichaelKnight/ValidandoFormularios.git

Comment: Can you do a clean build and check? Sometimes changes made to spring boot application might not reflect until the app is cleaned and built.

Comment: @harshavmb I just did it. Nothing new :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I got it!

Instead of the ClassName I had to use the object name and it works like a charm. `NotNull.person.age=THE AGE CANNOT BE NULL!!!!`

I uploaded the code to github for further references for any fellow member.

Comment: Works perfectly like this for me using Spring Boot 1.4.1

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using JSR-303 validators then you should place your messages to the file named `ValidationMessages.properties`. JSR-303 provider (hibernate-validator, in this case) looks by default for this file (as per specification).

See for details: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html/chapter-message-interpolation.html

Comment: Does it work if you will use `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message` instead of `NotNull.message` (in `ValidationMessages.properties`)?

Comment: Now we are talking. This is working nice in that way.

But this only solves my problem partially. What I really wanna do is assigning customized values to the error messages depending on the class as it is explained here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323655/thymeleaf-how-to-use-custom-message-key-in-jsr-303-annotation

If you require specific message for different fields, your message properties should include them in the following format: [constraintName.Class.field]. For example:

NotEmpty.Vehicle.model = Model cannot be empty!

Comment: Here also explains how to do it in the other way that still not working for me: 
http://blog.inflinx.com/2010/03/10/jsr-303-bean-validation-using-spring-3/

Answer (score 0):

As @Slava suggested the problem is in using JSR-303 validators.

Maybe this will help:

[Thymeleaf : How to use Custom Message Key in JSR-303 Annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323655/thymeleaf-how-to-use-custom-message-key-in-jsr-303-annotation)

Comment: that link is also included in the description of my issue. I followed it step by step with no result